# Parse user detail fail

Tags: php, android

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();

dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

try{
    HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "display_userAdvertisement.php");

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
    client.execute(post);
```

My PHP code

```
php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','synaptic','12345');

//define ('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80');
mysql_select_db("bruhbmvr_register",$con);

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "select * from post_ads WHERE email = '$email'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json['userinfo'][]=$row;
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

I'm trying to parse the email from the Android apps to the PHP file, but it is empty.

My question is how do I parse the email to PHP, and then directly show the details of the email in JSON format?

Comment: Start by ensuring that your PHP code is receiving the correct data in the request. Once you know on which side the problem is, you might be able to make progress.

Also, you should check that your calls to the DB are successful: Did mysql_connect succeed? Did mysql_saelect_db succeed? etc.

Comment: calls to the DB is succesfull, and correct data in request, but now i just dont know how to display the information into json encode.

Comment: Where do you want to show the details?

Comment: the moment i run the php file...

Comment: Do you want to display the information in a trace? Do you want to display an HTML page to the user?